# Page loader setup is to fast in localhost environment?

Tags: javascript, localhost, offline, preloader

I'm testing a jquery pageloader (queryloader2) offline, but 
even frequent browser cleaning, doesn't provide me the ability to see the preloading script in full action, as it zips by so quickly I don't know it it's even doing anything.

How I could simulate online speeds.

Thanks I'll take me answer offline. Dido.

Stackflow:
Your question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question. If the answers there do not address your problem, please edit to explain in detail the parts of your question that are unique.

(I've searched for a duplicate question, an answer to prevent me from asking. Thanks.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit Bandwidth per Apache Virtual Host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009248/limit-bandwidth-per-apache-virtual-host)

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a slower network connection with Chrome Developer Tools. The mode is intended for mobile device emulation, but you can turn off the screen resizing and just use the [network throttling](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#network-conditions) feature.

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools! Thanks so much for that suggestion.